What are the disadvantages of using an endurance gravel bike (with smooth tires) as an endurance road bike?
The advantages (for me) would be:

Common availability of 48t-34t chainrings, which are more suitable for my riding speeds. (I seldom, if ever, use the 52t/11-12t or 50t/12-13t gear combinations.)

Easy availability of top-tube bolts. Those provide a non-wobbly, guaranteed-scratch-free set-up for an up-front bag, which I find much more convenient for paper tissues and snacks than reaching into my back pockets. When drafting, back-pocket manoeuvres are also somewhat more risky than front-bag access.

The stack is often slightly higher for the same reach, providing a more comfortable geometry for someone who has no intention of racing.

I can remain in road-bike-territory tires (32 or 35 mm), and yet have substantial fork+frame clearances. These in turns will mean I can select routes that venture on mild gravel, even with ostensibly road-bike tires.


The only disadvantage I see so far is:

A penalty of ~1 kg in weight, for a roughly equivalent bike.

What are the other disadvantages? Would I, for example, be at a serious disadvantage staying with a group of riders most of whom are on road bikes? I would be using this bike to extend my current 100-110 km rides to 150-160 km. On those nose-wiping and feeding will only increase.

I went through a similar process a few months ago, and ended with the gravel bike. For the context, I had an upgraded hybrid, that I was already using in gravel group rides with success, but I joined a road club and "needed" something closer to a road bike.
After a market comparison, I also came to the conclusion that taking a gravel bike was the best option. Note that gravel is now splitting between "race" and "adventure", and the "race" ones are much closer to endurance road bikes in terms of total reach/stack (including stem and bars), but also tire clearance: some recent endurance road bikes can now reach 40mm tire clearance, and the sweet spot for gravel racing is also 40mm.
But I went for an "allrounder", designed prior to this split. The decision factors where:

I knew the state of the road in my area and knew what I would miss with a pure road bike. The total reach/stack values where very close to the equivalent endurance road bikes, so I considered that the aero benefit of the road bike was very limited.
More and more road multi-days events in Europe are now road and gravel, so having a single bike (with an possible wheel swap) that can do both was seen as a benefit.
Gravel bikes have generally more mounting points, but if you take a racy one, it's not a given.
Upgrade potential: the one I took has clearance for up to 47mm in 28" (and 55mm in 27.5"), clearance for 50/34 road cranks (note that it's not a given, more and more gravel bikes are 1x only) and the frame also allows a dropper post.
Note however that gravel bikes can be stiffer than road bikes: they are designed for rougher conditions, and designed with the assumption of having more rubber for cushioning.
An inconvenient could be linked to combination geometry/wide tires (gravel frames are often longer, which is compensated by shorter stems): a gravel bike will be less reactive to ride (both in steering and acceleration). If it is an important criteria, that may be a drawback.

So the short version is that gravel bikes are generally much more versatile than road bikes.
On my experience with using a gravel bike with roadies:

Absolutely no problem to use in road group rides. There are a few people in the club doing that as well, swapping wheels. There's a small aero penalty, that is mitigated when riding in peloton. The penalty would be higher when riding with the fastest groups, but I don't have the fitness for that anyway.
The 2x is often presented as a requirement to do that, but it's not the case as modern gravel cassettes are tightly spaced for the smaller half - there are two members using Ekar with road tires in the groups with a target speed of 28km/h, and they don't feel the need for 2x. I went for a 2x11 Shimano, as it was the only option to have a 580+% range and I considered that a requirement, but that doesn't apply to everyone.
I don't swap wheels or tires, but opted for a gravel race semi slick tire (Hutchinson Caracal Race, that rolls as well as a GP5000 according to Bicycle Rolling Resistance), and increase the pressure by 0.5-1bar when riding on road. If I were to swap tires, it would be for 45mm with knobs for mud conditions, the Caracal Race works in fact very well in dry conditions for gravel and road. I haven't tried pure road tires, but I don't see the need: I don't have the impression to be penalized by the bike, and when the road is in poor condition, the difference between 40mm and 28mm is visible.


Purely subjective as well, but having the mounting points for fenders allow to have proper full length fenders (that don't rattle and do not need clamping be mounted), which is appreciated by the people following me.

Even the aero penalty of the bike itself (as opposed to rider position) is variable down to really quite low, with internal cabling, aero carbon forks etc., and a lot of what does add staff is useful features for endurance (like mounting points)

The aero penalty I was thinking about was more linked to the wheels: larger frontal area and lack of availability of rims that comply to the 105 rule with 40mm tires. But it’s indeed only significant at speeds out of reach of most riders.

My opinion is that gravel bike is the bike you want to buy.
Some time ago, when gravel bikes weren't sold as gravel bikes, I would have recommended some kind of non-racing-oriented cyclocross bike or a touring bike with drop bars.
Today, gravel bike is the bike you want to buy.
Of course, the more comfortable riding position means you have more air resistance. But on the other hand, it means you can ride on the drops more often. I find it ridiculous that lots of people buy a drop bar bike and never ride on the drops. If you just moved the handlebars up a bit, you might ride on the drops when you want low air resistance, and then on the hoods, corners or tops otherwise.
1 kg in weight is nothing. Leave the water bottle home and you save 0.5-0.75 kg, if it isn't particularly hot weather. Of course 160 km in hot weather requires water, but then again it might require so much water that a single bottle won't do so the others have to stop for rewatering as well, and 160 km without having some food to eat at a lunch break sounds like an out-of-fuel condition.

“1 kg in weight is nothing.” for some people it’s 2% of their body weight (corresponding to a similar difference in speed when going uphill). A light bike is also easier to carry up or down stairs. Riding without water is a silly suggestion, it’s uncomfortable, bad for performance and possibly unhealthy.

I bought a gravel bike for this reason, as an upgrade from a rugged tourer, but with the option of doing some gravel. I run 2 wheelsets (gravel with 11-36 and road with 11-34) and the gravel tyres are surprisingly quick; I've done 200km days on them, mainly road with off-road at the far end, and the road sections are a very similar speed*.
I can run full mudguards with 32 or 35mm slicks, and I have a third bottle cage for my tools, just like the tourer but unlike most road bikes. I could fit a pannier rack (again unlike pure road bikes) but don't because I've still got the tourer if I need panniers and not just bikepacking bags.
You're right that light gravel and even some rather rough stuff is doable on those slightly wider road tyres. They're limited by grip on climbs, mud, or loose material, but you have to be unlucky for that to slow you down much.
Gravel and adventure road bikes are the common modern way to fill the niche that the light steel tourer used to, but lighter. And mine is 5kg lighter than my (definitely not light) tourer, which I used for my first endurance stuff.
In your case, thinking of going from 100s to 150s, you may find your riding style and preferred conditions evolve as well. That points to the more flexible bike. You're moving into 2-bottle territory if you're not there already, and might want to carry more tools/spares if you'll be further from home and out first longer.

*The big downside of gravel tyres on tarmac is reduced grip if I brake hard

Just a precision: the big downside you identify with "gravel tires" really depends on what you call a "gravel tire", as there's a bunch of them with different compromises, so it may be useful to identify what you consider a gravel tire. Semi-slicks won't have issues when braking, but may have a grip loss when leaning (may because it depends on the tire design - tread and width of the smooth rolling band).

@Rеnаud yes, in fact I considered saying "with my gravel tyres". They're the ones I got with the bike and perhaps not what I would have chosen but they roll nicely on mixed surface rides so I'm making the most of them. I also have some gravel tyres for the mtb with a coarser tread pattern but better braking grip - maybe a softer compound

There's no serious disadvantages outside of competitive racing.
The gravel bike, is, simply put, a modern version of the "everyday road bike", adapted for daily use on real city streets. The shift towards wider tires has been going on in road bikes for a while already. Gravels just took a leap ahead, taking lessons from cyclocross, but ditching the regulations.
On imperfect terrain, like a typical road, the wider tires and a smoother ride will typically get you from A to B just as fast as a slightly lower-drag racing road bike on skinny slicks.

With much respect for the time spent by those who answered, and with a lot of affection for those who have patted my back to assure me that a gravel bike will be a fine substitute for a road bike, I am looking for a counterpoint — or a devil's advocate argument if you're convinced a gravel is an adequate substitute. I am seeking arguments why a road bike still has its merits, even for non-racers — in other words, I'm seeking the disadvantages of the substitution.
Meanwhile I identified a few points.

As indicated in a comment, one should not quite so easily dismiss a 1000 g difference in weight. A 1 kg difference in weight translates to a ~1.5% slower speed on climbs for a 150 lb individual (how is that calculated, and why is it linear?). That might be enough for one to lose one's riding group.

A road bike will provide mount points for two bottles of water while a gravel bike will typically provide three (plus the more imaginative locations). Since two 710 ml (24 oz) bottles last me about 80 km, it's anyway better to seek refilling than to haul a third bottle for 80 km before starting to drink from it.

The colours of gravel bikes are downright dreadful: greys and beiges, basically. Yet whether I'm on trails that are seldom frequented by cars or riding a gravel bike on out-of-town roads, for safety I'd like to resemble as much as possible a blinking Christmas tree. Blending in the environment (saturation-free colours, flat paint jobs) seems like a bad idea.

Even if I adopt a gravel frame, the sturdier gravel wheels are problematic. I may need to change not just the tires, but also the wheels if they're heavier than road wheels. The increased moment of inertia means that it will harder to accelerate an to deccelerate. Both are critical, even when riding in a friendly (i.e., non-racing) peloton.



From my market research, the 1kg penalty was the maximum (Specialized Roubaix vs Diverge) rather than an average - out of which 400g are explained by the tires alone. But for the use case you describe, the comparison should rather be gravel race vs endurance, and it becomes less obvious (to remain with Specialized, the Crux is 400g lighter than the Roubaix - and with road tires, the difference should increase to 800g - extreme example as well as the Roubaix is on the heavy side, and the Crux is super light).

You definitely want to also change the wheels, without question. Changing wheels between rides is quick, changing tyres on wheels is pain in the arse, especially since gravel tyres should really be used tubeless.
